# For which composite $N$ does $X_0(N)$ possess a non-cuspidal rational point?

Tags: moduli-spaces, elliptic-curves, reference-request

According the the introduction to Mazur's *Rational Isogenies of Prime Degree* the following question was open in 1978:

> > Let $N$ be one of the integers 39, 65, 91, 125, or 169. Does the modular curve $X_0(N)$ possess noncuspidal rational points?

It seems likely that this should have been resolved in the past 32 years. Does anyone know of a reference for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me make David Brown's answer more explicit.

Theorem ([Kenku, 1979](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Kenku79.pdf)): $X_0(39)(\mathbb{Q})$ consists entirely of the ($4$) cuspidal points.

Theorem ([Kenku, 1980](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Kenku80.pdf)): $X_0(65)(\mathbb{Q})$ and $X_0(91)(\mathbb{Q})$ each consist entirely of the ($4$) cuspidal points.

Theorem ([Kenku, 1980](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Kenku80b.pdf), see also [Kenku, 1980](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Kenku81.pdf)): $X_0(169)(\mathbb{Q})$ consists entirely of $2$ rational cuspidal points.

Theorem ([Kenku, 1981](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Kenku81b.pdf)): $X_0(125)(\mathbb{Q})$ consists entirely of $2$ rational cuspidal points.

Answer (score 8):

These are all due to Kenku; see [mathscinet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?pg4=AUCN&s4=kenku&co4=AND&pg5=TI&s5=the+modular+curves&co5=AND&pg6=ALLF&s6=&co6=AND&pg7=REFF&s7=&co7=AND&Submit=Search&dr=all&yrop=eq&arg3=&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&pg8=ET&s8=All&review_format=html).